# ios - How to add image to favourite list when button clicked and show Then in another View

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui

I have a list of images which are stored in asset folder. All the images are listed on the screen as a grid and a favorite icon at the right bottom of each images. The idea is whenever the user clicks the favorite icon i would add it to a favorite list and display it in another view that only contains favorite images. The approach i took was when the user click the icon i will insert the position of the UIImage into an array and save it in to userDefault, but retrieving and displaying didn't work. I try to convert the image into Base64 string and store it in the array also did not seem the way to go.
If there is an approach you would suggest, I will appreciate it.

What i want is when the user click the icon display it in a separate favorite View.

Comment: Please provide the relevant parts of your code. This is for sure possible to achieve quite easily. You are on the right track. I would suggest you save the image names using CoreData and then fetch the image names back from CoreData on your "FavoriteView".

Comment: It's not quite clear if you need to store which are the preferred images definitively, or if you're just using the userdefault to pass that information from one screen to another.

Comment: @ClaudioCastro I'm trying to store permanently even if the app is closed. I'm not trying to store exactly the image too, i want to store the address or name of the image and load the image from that.